# Extern Stylesheet is shown like "inline" in Developer Tools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am using this Template:

http://www.pixelcoder.eu/pixopolus/Pixopolus/

when I inspect it for editing, the styles appear in the developer tools like inline styles in Chrome and also in Firefox. (Opera 12.xx + 16.xx and IE10 as well)

Any hints what is wrong, is there maybe a syntax error somewhere or how this can happen? I am using the same framework (bootstrap) for some other projects it never happened before.

Comment: could you provide some code? or jsfiddle maybe

Comment: <style media="screen" data-href="css/supersized.css">/*
*/all style elemts are listed inside the index.html*/
</style>

Its how the index.html for example look like, all external stylesheet files are listed inside the index.html.. when I open up the example link on the top for example.. In the Developer Toolbar its shows line numbers but the location is "index.html"..so weird. I try to make a code screenshot and upload it to image-shack.

Comment: http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/2259/ndd4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you link the stylesheets to the index.html. If i noticed correctly you are using the `<style>` tag to link the stylesheets.
I would sugest using the `<link>` tag like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" media="screen"/>`. I tested it on your page and it worked :D

Comment: thank you so much! that brought me something to mind. I use "prefixfree.js" and here is the problem. I deleted it and now the Css files are correctly shown with the link tag and the developer tools are working correctly.

Comment: It was a pleasure to help :D